# Extract domain name from string using PHP

Tags: php

How can I extract domain name from string like "AmericanSwan.com Indian Websites" ?

I am tried many options but none of them provide domain name.

Comment: did you used substr()?

Comment: Do you want just domain name like 'AmericanSwan'?

Comment: substr() will work if I know string "domain name" which I want to search. Actually I have CSV with more than 1000 rows and each row may have different domain name which is not predefined.

Comment: you said the source is a csv file. Would you open the file in notepad and print a couple of lines exactly as they appear? It will determine the best solution

Comment: I already have open file and loop is working. I just wanted to extra domain name from particular column for each row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below Regular Expression for extracting domain name from string, Try:

```
$input = 'AmericanSwan.com Indian Websites';
preg_match_all('#[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]*)?#si', $input, $result);
echo $result[0][0]; //$result will give list of all domain names of string, you can also loop through it
```

Output:

```
AmericanSwan.com
```

Comment: This doesn't work if a URI path is attached to the domain.  For example, with input `website.com/page.php`, it doesn't return just the domain; it also includes the path

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to this function: [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

And this example: [parse_url example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php#refsect1-function.parse-url-examples)